# Bootstrap 3, thumbnailed navigation carousel. Selected thumnail

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, carousel

I have used this example: http://www.bootply.com/79859
I copied it, and renamed #MyCarousel in #MyCarousele, also I deleted uneccesary slides. But it do not work corectly.

When it slides automatically or I slide it thumbnails do not updates. I think problem is somewhere here:

```
<script>
     $('#myCarousele').carousel({
     interval: 4000
     });

     // handles the carousel thumbnails
     $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
     var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
     var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
     id = parseInt(id);
     $('#myCarousele').carousel(id);
     $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
     });

    // when the carousel slides, auto update
    **$('#myCarousele').on('slid', function (e)** {
    var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
    id = parseInt(id);
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
    });
</script>
```

Look my bootply code: http://www.bootply.com/0cDXKzY1ez
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3.2, you need to change 'slid' to 'slid.bs.carousel'

Here would be your new code for that function:

```
$('#myCarousele').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   

     var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
     id = parseInt(id);
     $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
     $('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected'); 

});
```

Note that the example you linked is using Bootstrap 3.0 and you are using Bootstrap 3.2, you can find the commit that caused the change [here i believe.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/c2c19a4d2d45d8ccb5c84d293dea35a94148c9a4)

**Update**

Based on your update in the comments, try this:

```
$('#myCarousele').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).find('.item.active').data('slide-number');

    id = parseInt(id);
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
    });
```

Comment: mmm. At bootply work fine. But on my project did'nt... But I use 3.20 with bootswatch theme.

Comment: Its because I have two carousels. I declared both, but no hapiness.((

Comment: You are welcome. The reason it wasn't working is because you have two div's with class="active item", one for each carousel, so your code couldn't find the correct slide number. Adding $(this).find points to the carousel with id = myCarousel.